# Assigning function that returns a reference to non-reference type

Tags: c++, reference

I've encountered something I hadn't seen before and am trying to make sense of it.

If I have a function that returns an reference to something, it seems that when I call that function, I can assign the returned reference to a variable declared as a reference to the type, or a variable declared as the type itself, and nothing changes.

Here is a basic example that demonstrates what I'm talking about:

```cpp
int size = 150;
std::vector<int> v1(size);

void init(){
   for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
       v1[i] = i;
   }
}

std::vector<int>& foo(){
   return v1;
}

int main(){
   init();
   std::vector<int> v2 = foo();
   std::vector<int>& v3 = foo();

   for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
     std::cout<<v2[i]<<" ";
   }
   std::cout<<"\n";
   for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
     std::cout<<v3[i]<<" ";
   }
   std::cout<<"\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain to me exactly how it is that `v2` and `v3` can both be assigned with the same function?

I'm embarrassed to say that I honestly would have thought that one of these wouldn't even compile. I've noted that changing `v3` also changes the contents of `v1`, but changing `v2` does nothing to `v1`, so it makes sense to me when one would be preferable to the other. However, I'm having difficulty reconciling the fact that both assignments work.

What's going on here?

Comment: `foo()` returns a reference to `v1`. So `std::vector<int> v2 = v1;` makes a copy of the whole vector and `std::vector<int>& v3 = v1;` makes a reference to `v1` called `v3`.

Comment: One makes a copy of the vector, the other works on the same vector.  Guess which one of those `foo()` calls does each.

Comment: I guess what I'm not understanding here is that I've said foo should return a reference, so how can I assign it to something that is not declared as a reference?

Comment: That's how C++ works.  If the type on the left side of the `=` is not a reference, a copy is made.  Try it with any type, not just `std::vector`.  You will get the same behavior.

Comment: Either that point was glossed over in my education, or I wasn't paying attention. Definitely good to know. Thank you!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is that strictly speaking how C++ works, or is that how `operator=` generally tends to work and specifically how `std::vector`'s implementations of it work?

Comment: Well yes, `operator =` expected behavior should be the caveat.

Comment: @NathanPierson well, yes, you can always overload `=` to do something different. What probably should have been said is "because the type on the left isn't a reference, `operator=` is called".

Comment: Technically, `operator=` is not actually being called in this example. The statement `std::vector<int> v2 = foo();` is identical to `std::vector<int> v2(foo());` ie it calls `v2`'s copy constructor instead, which accepts a `vector&` reference as input.

Answer (score 2):

```
   std::vector<int> v2 = foo();
   std::vector<int>& v3 = foo();
```

v2 is copy of v1 (new memory locations) while v3 is a reference to v1 (same memory locations)

What this means is that the address of v1 (&v1) and the address of v2 (&v2) are NOT the same.
However the &v1 == &v3

Therefore, when making changes to the elements of v2, then v1 will NOT be changed.

But, making changes to elements of v3 WILL change v1.

WHY?? Because they both "*point*" to the same location in memory.